# Run appium scripts in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins

We are using maven serenity appium framework for native mobile application testing. I have appium driver local service and emulator desiredcapabilities in my program (so appium server and emulator starts automatically before program starts).

Attached my Jenkins file .When i try to build using Maven build steps, it's fails following error.

How to configure my appium framework in Jenkins,so it starts my appium server and program automatically from my script.

Can somebody explains step by step clearly please?

Note: We are not using browserstack or saucelabs.

```
pipeline {

    options {
       timestamps()
       disableConcurrentBuilds()
       buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '20'))
       skipStagesAfterUnstable()
   }

    triggers {
       pollSCM('H * * * *')
    }

    agent {
        label 'android-mobile'
    }

    stages {

        stage('Run smoke tests') {
            steps {
                wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', 'colorMapName': 'xterm']) {
                  copyArtifacts(projectName: "mob-TWLAndroid/develop", target: "Serenity_Framework/src/test/resources/APK")
                  sh "ls -al ."
                  sh "ls -al Serenity_Framework/src/test/resources/APK/AppName"
                  sh "cd Serenity_Framework && ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk mvn verify -Dcontext=Android -Dproperties=Android.properties"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Jenkins Failure:
[INFO] Test results for 0 tests generated in 12.1 secs in directory: <https://jenkins-ibm.twg.co.nz/job/android/ws/target/site/reports/SerenityBDD/>
Security framework of XStream not explicitly initialized, using predefined black list on your own risk.
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
[INFO]  SERENITY TESTS : SUCCESS
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
[INFO] | Tests executed         | 0
[INFO] | Tests passed           | 0
[INFO] | Tests failed           | 0
[INFO] | Tests with errors      | 0
[INFO] | Tests compromised      | 0
[INFO] | Tests pending          | 0
[INFO] | Tests ignored/skipped  | 0
[INFO] ------------------------ | --------------
[INFO] | Total Duration         | 000ms
[INFO] | Fastest test took      | 000ms
[INFO] | Slowest test took      | 000ms
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] SERENITY REPORTS
[INFO]   - Full Report: file://<https://jenkins-ibm.twg.co.nz/job/android/ws/target/site/reports/SerenityBDD/index.html>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:verify (default) @ AndroidSerenityFramework ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 05:34 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-18T01:04:02Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:verify (default) on project AndroidSerenityFramework: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to <https://jenkins-ibm.twg.co.nz/job/android/ws/target/failsafe-reports> for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
```

Comment: There's not enough information in your output to debug this.

Can you re-run with the -e and/or -X switch to provide more debug output, please?